# Supremum involving matrices and vectors

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $\lambda > 0$, $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, $u, z \in \mathbb R^n$, and $y \in \mathbb R^m$.
I want to compute
$$
\sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - \lambda \| u\|_1 - \langle y, Au\rangle)
$$

So far, I tried to calculate $\sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - \lambda \| u\|_1)$ by using the dual norm of $z$. For example, assume $\| z\|_* \leq \lambda$, then $\langle z, u\rangle \leq \| z\|_* \| u\|_1 \leq \lambda \| u\|_1 \iff \langle z, u\rangle - \lambda \| u\|_1 \leq 0$, thus $\sup_{u} (\langle z, u\rangle - \lambda \| u\|_1) = 0$. However, I'm stuck with the $\| z\|_* > \lambda$ case, and the term $\sup_{u} (-\langle y, Au\rangle)$.

Comment: What is the set over which the supremum is taken? Is it in the form of $\{\|u\|_1\le C\}$ or something else?

Comment: @user1551: $u \in \mathbb R^n$

Comment: If $u$ is not bounded, isn't it usually the case that the supremum is infinity?

Comment: @user1551: I think you might be right. However, with that same argument, couldn't we conclude that $\sup_{u}(\langle z, u\rangle - \lambda\| u\|_1)$ is infinity too? (which is false for certain values of z)$

Comment: If $u$ is unbounded, then the supremum is either $+\infty$ or $0$. If you know how to compute $\sup_u (\langle z,u\rangle - \lambda \|u\|_1)$, you can solve the generalized problem by setting $z' = z-A^Ty$ and using $\langle y,Au \rangle = \langle A^Ty,u\rangle$.

Comment: @SolubleFish: Great. I think that will do it. I wasn't aware of $\langle y, Au \rangle = \langle A^ty, u\rangle$. Does it always hold?

Comment: Look up *hermitian adjoint*. In a space with a scalar product, it will work (with the usual transpose operation) when the basis is orthonormal.

Comment: If $u$ is unbounded, It isn't hard to show that the supremum is $+\infty$ when $|w_i|>\lambda$ for some $i$, or $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $w=z-A^Ty$.